# Recurring text in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I find myself re-writing the same answer to people interested in our products. How can I get the most common ones from a dropdown list in Outlook 2013?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Outlook 2007 you can add "Quick Parts" to an email. These Quick Parts could contain the answers you are required to repeat regularly. The Quick Parts drop down menu is found on the "Insert" tab within the sub group "Text" when composing a new email. I believe the same functionality is also within Outlook 2013.